# can't access helm .Values from a named template with non global context passed in

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to use a Helm named template that I plan to include with several different contexts, and the template has many values that are the same for all contexts.

Whenever I pass a context to `template` or `include` to invoke the named template, the references to `.Values` do not work, which is understandable because I'm explicitly setting a lower context.

In [the Helm documentation for `with`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#modifying-scope-using-with), it claims there is a "global" variable `$` that will allow reference to the global `.Values`, *e.g.*, `{{ $.Values... }}`.  This does not work (the example below shows the error).

I've also tried [defining variables](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/) (using `:=`) and "enclosing" the include inside that variable definition (via indentation - I don't know if it matters) to make that variable available within the named template, but this doesn't work either.

I've also tried putting these in "globals" as described [here](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/) which is more of a subchart thing and this doesn't work either.

So, I'm out of Helm tricks to make this work and will sadly have to re-define these many same variable many times - which makes the entire named template solution a bit less elegant - or just go back to having largely duplicate partially-parameterized templates.

What am I missing?

```
$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.9+unreleased", GitCommit:"", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Values.yaml:

```yaml
---
commonSetting1: "common1"
commonSetting2: "common2"
context1:
  setting1: "c1s1"
  setting2: "c1s2"
context2:
  setting1: "c2s1"
  setting2: "c2s2"
```

deployment.yaml:

```yaml
---
{{- define "myNamedTemplate" }}
      - name: {{ .setting1 }}
        image: {{ $.Values.commonSetting1 }}

{{- include "myNamedTemplate" .Values.context1 }}
{{- include "myNamedTemplate" .Values.context2 }}
```

```
$ helm template test-0.1.0.tgz 
Error: render error in "test/templates/deployment.yaml": template: test/templates/deployment.yaml:7:4: executing "test/templates/deployment.yaml" at <include "myNamedTemp...>: error calling include: template: test/templates/deployment.yaml:4:19: executing "myNamedTemplate" at <$.Values.commonSetti...>: can't evaluate field commonSetting1 in type interface {}
```

Answer (score 8):

When I do this, I tend to explicitly pass in the top-level context object as a parameter.  This gets a little tricky because the Go text/template templates only take a single parameter, so you need to use the (Helm/Sprig) [`list`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#lists-and-list-functions) function to package multiple parameters together, and then the (standard text/template) `index` function to unpack them.

The template definition would look like:

```yaml
{{- define "myNamedTemplate" }}
{{- $top := index . 0 }}
{{- $context := index . 1 }}
- name: {{ $context.setting1 }}
  image: {{ $top.Values.commonSetting1 }}
{{ end }}
```

When you invoke it, you would then need to explicitly pass the current context as a parameter:

```yaml
{{ include "myNamedTemplate" (list . .Values.context1) }}
```

Comment: This works perfectly!   Thank you!  I have so little reputation I can't upvote it, but I'd upvote it 50 times if I could.  I wish this were documented in the helm documents more clearly somewhere, this is a very useful technique.